# How to tell from my C++ code if it's running on Intel x86_64 vs ARM64 architecture?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, x86-64, arm64

How to tell if my compiled C++ macOS app is running on AMR64 vs Intel x86-64 architecture?

PS. I need this for logging purposes.

Comment: since you need two different compile runs for these two different targets, you can just as well already detect that  at compile. The link I shared above explains how.

Comment: Are you looking for a bit of magic you can pull after the fact? As in you can't simply build in a function that tells you?

Comment: Hint:  The platform information is either supplied to the compiler; or it is already known by the compiler.  So why not ask the compiler by checking predefined macros?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's what I was asking. Xcode and Mach-O file format supports binaries with dual architectures, so I wanted to know which one my compiled code is running under. So it seems like for Xcode `#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(i386)` will mean x86 and `#elif defined(__aarch64__)` will mean ARM64.